# How to Create Rounded Search Box

Tags: html, css, textfield

I have a div with a size of 190x30 pixels, and a background image of the same. The background image is a rounded rectangle and it looks good. When I put the text field in the div, the background repeats vertically, so for some reason, the search box is requiring 60 px of vertical space... WHY? 
I should add that in DreamWeaver it appears correctly, but in Chrome or IE, it doesn't.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Answer (score 7):

CSS:

```
.round {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}

.corner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    background: #000; /* Set the bg image here. with "no-repeat" */
}

.search {
    position: relative;
    width: 190px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

HTML :

```
<form id="search-form">
    <div class="search">
      <input type="text" name="search" class="round" />
      <input type="submit" class="corner" value="" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Bh4g3/

Comment: I've tried that, but I want to have an image within that div/input, that when clicked, submits the form.

Comment: that's just a quick solution, you can give the <a> tag the "corner" class, and set it's bg image as you require.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent the background from repeating, use this CSS declaration:

```
#element {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: You can adjust the placement of the background image with `background-position: 0px 50px;` or similar (see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp). If you post your code, it'll be easier for us to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this
CSS

```
#divName { background:url("image-src) no-repeat; height:30px; width:190px; }
```

HTML

```
<div id="divName"><input type="text" ></div>
```

And you may put anything inside the div "divName"

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

CSS:

```
.example input[type=text] {
       border-radius: 25px;
      }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="example">
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
       </div>
```

Here's a fiddle to see how it looks like:

```css
.example input[type=text] {
  border-radius: 25px splid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <div class="example">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better in this way:

```
<input placeholder="Search..." type="search" value="" id="search"
         onchange="openPage()">

<script>
    function openPage() {
        var x = document.getElementById("search").value;

        if (x === "Home") {
            window.open("home.html");
        }

        if (x === "About") {
            window.open("about.html");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).